# Set a value in Model via javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, model

I have this code:

```
public class AccountModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Subscription ID")]
    public string SubscriptionId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Storage Name")]
    public string StorageName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Storage Key")]
    public string StorageKey { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Hosted Name")]
    public string HostedName { get; set; }
....
}
```

and...

```
$('a.sign-in').live('click', function () {
            alert("BINGO!");

            var id = document.getElementById('id').value;
            var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
            var key = document.getElementById('key').value;
            var select = document.getElementById("listahosted");
            var selected = select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;
...
}
```

I just want to set a value on my model -> put the "selected" value in the model m.HostedName
How can I do this?

Regards

UPDATE WITH MY VIEW

My view

```
@model WebManager.Models.AccountModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Account";
}

<h2>Account</h2>
<p>
Please enter your Azure account details.
</p>

@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Invalid account. Please correct the errors and try again.")

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<div>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Account Information</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SubscriptionId)
        </div>
       <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SubscriptionId, new { id = "id"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SubscriptionId)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.StorageName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StorageName, new { id = "name" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.StorageName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.StorageKey)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StorageKey, new { id = "key" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.StorageKey)
        </div>

        <p>
            <a href="#login-box" class="login-window">
                <input type="submit" value="Apply" /></a>
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</div>

<div id="login-box" class="login-popup">
    <!--a href="#" class="close"><img src="close_pop.png" class="btn_close" title="Close Window" alt="Close" /></a-->
    <form method="post" class="signin" action="#">
    <fieldset class="textbox">
        <label class="hostedservice">
            <span>Hosted Service</span>
            <br />
            <select id='listahosted' name='listahosted'>
            <option>Choose your hosted</option>
            </select>
        </label>
        <br />
        <label class="deployments">
            <span>Role</span>
            <br />
            <select id='listadeployments' name='listadeployments'>
            <option>Choose your role</option>
            </select>
        </label>
        <br />
        <a class="sign-in">
        <input type="submit" value="Sign In" /></a>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

I am not putting here the javascript.

The situation is: I have a combobox filled by JS and I need to put the selected value on my model.

All help is apreciated

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET MVC3? The tag seperation makes this unclear?

Comment: What does your view look like?

Comment: Yes, I am using ASP.NET MVC3. Sorry but I can't understand what you meant with tag seperation.

Comment: Add your rendered form or at least a part of it to the question and someone will get you an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I noticed was that you are putting `submit` fields inside your `a` tags.  You should not do this.  I would just use a `button` tag with `type="submit"`.

The names of your `input` or `select` elements must match the property name in your model.  In this case `listahosted` needs to be `HostedName`.  It might be easier to use the `HtmlHelper` for select lists.  This way if you change the property name in the model, your view will at least YSOD instead of missing the error.

So if you want this all to be ajax, do something like this:

```
// You should use a button element instead of anchor but anchor will work...
$('a.sign-in').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $("form");            
    $.ajax({
        url : form.attr('action'),
        data : form.serialize(),
        success : function(data) {
            // do whatever you need to here
        }
    });
});​
```

Comment: thanks for your tips and help. Data is supposed to have the "serialized form" right? Now how can I get the values from comboxes and put them in the model?

Comment: Yes, if you use the HTML helper for select list and bind it to the `HostedName` property, it will work as expected.  You will not need to manually set the name on the select lists.